# how to access nested firebase collection with its parent collection

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am developing a forum application, in which user can ask question and get answer(each answer have its own like)
What I want is when I access answer i want to get it subcollection of like with it. But I don't know how to access the "likes" collection. I have google and found method of collection group queries but dont have sufficient knowledge of firebase. Would anybody help me to get "likes"

```
getcomments(id) {
  this.commentcollection = this.questioncollection.doc(id).collection<Comment>('answer');
  this.comments = this.commentcollection
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(changes =>{
      return changes.map(a=>{
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Question;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      })
    }));
  return this.comments;
}
```

Here am get comment collection,

```html
<li *ngFor="let comment of selectedComment |async">
  <div class="comment-main-level">
    <div class="comment-box">
      <div class="comment-head">
        <span>{{comment.time.toDate() | date: 'dd MMM hh:mm'}}</span>
        <i>Likes</i>
        <i (click)="likepost(comment.userID,comment.id)" class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
        <i (click)="editComment($event, comment)" *ngIf="comment.userID==authService.currentUserId" class="fa fa-pencil-alt">  </i>
        <i (click)="deleteComment(comment.id)" *ngIf="comment.userID==authService.currentUserId" class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-content">
        {{comment.answerBody}}
      </div>
```

This is my html where I'm showing comment, I want to show like of every comment at  tag.
How I can get like collection.
[image]

Comment: Likes do not need their own entity / collection. Just add a property (type int) to the comment entity...

Comment: I want to show a list of likes if user click on number of likes

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can do it similar way as you access the `answer` collection in `getcomment` function. Nested collection of document can be accessed by `collection` method and nested document in collection by `doc` method. This can be all over again until you reach last level of your structure - like this:

```
parentCollectionReference.doc(<docid>).collection(<nestedCollectionId>).doc(<nestedDocId>).collection(<collectionNestedInNestedDoc>).doc... etc.
```

I understand that you will have document id of answer the user will pick. Lets say its `anwserId`. You have as well collectionReference to `answer` collection as you are already accessing it in `getcomment` - lets say it's `this.commentcollection`. The logic will be exactly the same as in `getcomment` method. Main difference that you have to get reference to proper subcollection. The pseudo code will look like this:

```
this.likeCollection = this.commentcollection.doc('anwserId').collection<Likes>('likes');
```

All the rest can be similar logic to the `getcomment` function.